# Is it legal to define a function like this?

Tags: functions

So I need to do something recursively and count how many steps it takes and I've come up with something like this:

$$ f(x)= \begin{cases}
             f(\operatorname{Re}(x)+1)+i,  & \operatorname{Re}(x) \text{ is not prime} \\
             \\ \operatorname{Im}(x), &\operatorname{Re}(x)\text{ is prime}
             \end{cases}
$$

Comment: What does prime mean if $x$ is complex?

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb C$, then this is not really a recursion, you are missing the base case(s)

Comment: Oops I fixed it, I wanted a thing to see how far away the next nearest prime was.

Comment: What is $f(\pi)$ with this definition? (What is the intended domain of definition for $f$?)

Comment: The domain of the function is the positive integers @mrf

Comment: Then why the real and imaginary parts

Comment: The real part is the actual integer we are putting in and the imaginary part is the count to see how far away the next prime is @Blazej

Comment: If $x$ is a positive integer, then surely $\operatorname{Im}(x) = 0$?

Comment: Yes but for every time Re(x) is not prime we add i which basically acts as a counter to see how far away the next nearest prime is so the only time f(x) will return a 0 is if Re(x) is prime @mrf

Comment: This seems to do what you want,  but your notation for it is odd.  $x $ is its own real part and the imaginary part is 0.

Comment: @Matt This is true for $x$, but not necessarily for its images and its images and ... . As these are plugged into $f$ as well, his notation seems fine.

Comment: So its fine to define a function like this? @Stefan

Comment: Hmm, seems like you're getting locked up for a long, long time.

Comment: @Ghost Personally, I'd prefer another notation (using pairs of integers instead of complex numbers), but yeah... this yields a well-defined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a function from the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) (complex numbers of the form $x+iy$ with $x,y$ real integers) to the Gaussian integers, this is a well defined recursive function. The calculation of $f(x+iy)$ with terminate for real integers $x,y$.

Whether it has the properties you want  or is efficient is another matter. For example:

- $f(11)=0$
- $f(10)=f(11)+i = i$
- $f(9)=f(10)+i= 2i$
- $f(11+5i) = 5$
- $f(10+5i) = f(11)+i = i$
- $f(9+5i) = f(10)+i = 2i$

Comment: Yeah it seems to have to properties i want and i don't care vary much if its efficient or not.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of complex numbers is misleading, however, after having the domain specified $\left(x\in\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\Bbb Z, a>0\}\right)$, your solution *seems to work*. (Maybe it's $f(x)=f(x+1)+i$ what you want for not prime $x$.)

You can use a binary real function to do the same:
$$f(x,n):=\left\{\matrix{f(x+1,n)\,+1 & \mbox{if }x\mbox{ is not prime}\\
n & \mbox{if }x\mbox{ is prime}}\right.$$
Then your final function will be $\color{blue}f(x):=f(x,0)$.

Or.. why not just write the following?
$$f(x):=p-x\ \mbox{ where }p\mbox{ is the next prime }\ge x $$